# "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Toolkit not initialized" when exporting project to jar

Tags: java, javafx, initialization

When I launch my application in my development enviroment(Eclipse) it runs, however, when I try to export it to a runnable .jar-file, it gives me the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at mallApp.MainTwo.<clinit>(MainTwo.java:24)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:59)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Toolkit not initialized
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.runLater(PlatformImpl.java:410)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.runLater(PlatformImpl.java:405)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.setPlatformUserAgentStylesheet(PlatformImpl.java:695)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.setDefaultPlatformUserAgentStylesheet(PlatformImpl.java:657)
    at javafx.scene.control.Control.<clinit>(Control.java:99)
    ... 4 more
```

With "Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Toolkit not initialized" being the issue.

There are numerous threads here about similar issues, but none of them seem to be quite the same, and the fixes that I have tried do not work for me. My class extends Application and therefore has Application.launch(args) in the main method. This should initialize the Toolkit but it does not for some reason when exported to a .jar.

When I try to add the Toolkit in a different way, for example using JFXPanel or `Platform.startup(Runnable)`, it gives me the opposite error, saying that Toolkit is already initialized.

```
public class MainTwo extends Application {

        ...

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    @Override
    public void start(Stage arg0) throws Exception {
        model = new Main2Model();
        c = model.getCompanyList();
        primaryStage = arg0;
        primaryStage.setTitle("MallApp");
        primaryStage.centerOnScreen();
        showMainView();
    }
```

Comment: Probably not clear enough from the description, but I mean that the error occurs when executing the jar-file and not when exporting it.

Comment: What is line 24 in `MainTwo.java`? Do you initialize a `static` field with some `Control` there?

Comment: @fabian It is "private static Company selectedStore;" So its a static field, but it's not control, its a seperate class. I don't have any Control imported to main:

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

Comment: I do have a lot of static object in that class though, does that cause the issue?

Comment: It would be best if you could [edit] your question to provide a [mre] demonstrating the issue. The problem is definitely caused by some static block/field in your class, as evidenced by the `<clinit>` in the first stack frame. The stack trace also indicates you're using the JAR-in-a-JAR packaging provided by Eclipse; does the problem persist when the dependencies are not all embedded in one JAR file?

Comment: @Slaw I've tried all three options for creating the Jar, with the libraries in a separate folder etc, same outcome. Could you perhaps explain how a static object would cause the issue? I could rework the code into a finer model with less static fields if that was the case, but I'm interested into why there is this issue. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: I'm not sure what _specifically_ is causing the problem. All I can say is something is happening during class initialization that requires the JavaFX toolkit to be initialized when it's not. Could you provide a [mre], please? Whatever the issue, avoiding static state is typically preferable.

Comment: I'm sorry that I could not provide an example for you, but I have solved the issue thanks to you and @fabian. The problem was that I had initialized private static javafx-attributes when I declared them. I moved their initialization to start(Stage arg0) and now I can run the JAR.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was that I had initialized static javafx-attributes when i declared them. The issue was resolved and the JAR became runnable when I moved the initalization of the fields to the start-method as shown below:

Instead of having:

```
private static TextField total = new TextField();
private static ObservableList<String> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

public void start(Stage arg0) throws Exception {
    model = new Main2Model();
    c = model.getCompanyList();
    primaryStage = arg0;
    primaryStage.setTitle("MallApp");
    primaryStage.centerOnScreen();
    showMainView();
}
```

I have:

```
private static TextField total;
private static ObservableList<String> items;

@Override
public void start(Stage arg0) throws Exception {
    total = new TextField();
    items = FXCollections.observableArrayList(); 
    model = new Main2Model();
    c = model.getCompanyList();
    primaryStage = arg0;
    primaryStage.setTitle("MallApp");
    primaryStage.centerOnScreen();
    showMainView();
}
```